# How can I Jira issues by status within a specific project?

Tags: rest, api, jira

I'm making a call to the Jira API as follows:

`https://synergix.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project="PROJECT_KEY"`

This gets me back issues in that project. However, what I really would like is to get the issues back in the project by STATUS e.g. all the issues within that project that are "In Progress" or "Open" or "Resolved" etc.

I have explored Stack Overflow and Jira's documentation for an answer but a lot of the answers seem to relate to getting issues by status for multiple projects, whereas I want them just for THIS project key (as that's the one my team are working on).

Can anyone help please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *jql* parameter present in your URL accepts any [JQL syntax](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-764478330.html), so you may add `and (status="STATUS" or status="STATUS2")` to your parameter.

Example: `https://synergix.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project="PROJECT_KEY"%20and%20(status="In Progress"%20or%20status%20=%20"Open")`

Answer (score 0):

I think the JQL you're looking for is this: 
**project = Product key**   // within your project
**AND  issuetype = Story**   //by story
**AND  status in ("open", "In Progress", "Closed")** // the statuses you'd like to see
**order by statu**s  // ordered by, you guessed it, status

I'm not sure how to format it for the Jira API, but I'm sure there's a fairly straightforward translation.